# GenemuFormBundle - jQuery rating - token input rendered as a star

Tags: symfony, jquery-plugins

I'm working on Symfony2 based website, using GenemuFormBundle for the rating system which use the jQuery rating plugin.

When I use the FormType from the bundle, I always have one more star at the end. It's the hidden input token being rendered.

My guess is that the js part that is initializing the jquery-rating plugin doesn't filter the input tags. But I don't know what to change, it might be my FormType configuration. The documentation is quite light on this bundle.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Here is my test code (PHP) :

```
$options = array('number' => 5, 'configs' => array('readOnly' => true));

$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new RatingType(), 2, $options);

return $this->templating->render($name, $parameters + array(
    'ratingForm'  => $form->createView()
));
```

TWIG :

```
{{form_widget(ratingForm)}}
{{form_javascript(ratingForm)}}
```

The result is a 6 stars rating. The first 5 are ok but when hovering the last one, the title is the token value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way to solve my problem.

It happens because the csrf protection token input has the same name as the rating input. (I guess it because the formtype is not supposed to be used like this) So when the jQuery part applies its magic to all input having the same name, it takes the token too.

What I did to avoid this, was adding an option `'csrf_protection' => false` to the formType.

```
$options = array('number' => 5, 'configs' => array('readOnly' => true), 'csrf_protection' => false);
```